# How to set tags on Gitlab runner instances?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

The documentation specifies how to set tags on the job side so it only runs on runners equipped with the right tags:

```
osx job:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - osx
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $USER!"
```

However, I couldn't find how to set these tags on the runner itself. With the previous example, how can I set "osx" as a tag on my runner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either set this either when registering the runner:

```
gitlab-runner register --tag-list "osx,foo,bar" #...
```

Or you can edit the tags of an already-registered runner using the GitLab UI by clicking the edit icon on the runner list and editing the tag list:

[image: runner edit]

Comment: For a group runner, you can find the runner list under Groups -> Build -> Runners